# Prevent Length-Based Message Framing tampering?

Tags: c#, networking, tcp

For my TCP based network application I am transmitting data using length based message framing. It's quite simple, a packet looks like this:

```
[Length][Data]
```

Length is an Int32 telling me the length of the upcoming raw data.

I read the Int and create a `byte array` like this:

```
//Read Int
activePacketLength = (Int32)(bytes[0] | (bytes[1] << 8) | (bytes[2] << 16) | (bytes[3] << 24));
packetBuffer = new byte[activePacketLength]; //Create buffer
```

Then I read until I have read x bytes. It works fine, but what if some funny user sends me something like this:

```
0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0x7F 0x01 0x02 0x03 ... {and so on}
```

My code will create a new `byte array` with the size of `int.MaxValue` (~ 2GB) and will read data until I get a `OutOfMemoryException` or so ...

What is a good way to prevent tempering with this? I could implement a size limit (e.g. 1MB per packet, everything higher than that will discard the client and block it) but are there more "standard" solutions which do not feel so hacky?

Comment: Actually, four 0xFF bytes would yield -1 as you cast to `Int32`, which is signed. Anyway, the client sending that would be a bug. You could guard against obviously out-of-range values, but I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: Yeah right, I was first using UInt. I'll change the question :) So you think I should limit it and adjust the value according to my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot prevent a client from sending data you consider invalid you must check if the data are invalid. This includes limiting the length  of a frame (and thus the value of the length prefix) to the maximum size expected from a non-malicious client. If authentication is part of the protocol it would even be better to have two limits: a small one for non-authenticated clients which should just allow frame sizes needed for authentication and then a larger limit for authenticated clients.

Comment: That's a good idea with the different limits. I guess I will implement it this way, even though this approach feels "amateurish" to me, but that's just me and I think there is no other solution then. Thanks for your answer!